# Winsock udp recv not receiving all data even within a loop

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I have some UDP recv code utilizing winsock, specifically AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, and IPPROTO_UDP. The recv call exists in a loop that reads until all data is received. The problem is that I only get partial data every time. Furthermore I shouldn't even need the loop since I can see that all the data exists in a single packet. In wireshark I see that the real data length is 299 bytes. Wireshark successfully sees the entire packet so I know the packet sender is working correctly.

With my windows UDP code I only get 8 bytes until my receive method returns. I can see that the UDP code is stopping when it sees a 00 byte. Wireshark is able to read past those 00 bytes but windows udp recv is not able to read past it. It seems like windows sees the 00 as the end and therefore concludes that the packet is only 8 bytes.

I have looked at the header in wireshark and I see that the length specified is correct so i'm very confused as to why its only reading 8 bytes. Thank you for your help in advance.

This is what my receive call looks like for reference:

```
int ret = recv(socket, buffer, 1500, 0);
```

ret becomes 8 and buffer, which has been allocated to be 1500 bytes, is only filled with 8 bytes

Comment: winsock or winsock2?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think its winsock. Should I be using winsock2?

Comment: My downvote (I can't speak for any other): Consider how difficult it is to debug software when you cannot see said software. It's like going to the mechanic with a car problem and leaving the car at home. There are countless reasons you could be running into this, such as using `strlen` on binary data, and there is no way for us to narrow in on the correct problem or family of problems other than dumb luck. Your question cannot be answered, and this  makes it "Not useful".

Comment: tried both winsock2 and winsock and both have the same problem

Comment: um, how could there be countless reasons? There is no strlen. The recv call is quite simple and mine is just recv(socket, buffer, default_buffer_length, 0). Default buffer length is 1500 and buffer has been initialized to be size of 1500. I'm not sending data, i'm receiving data so what does strlen have to do with it? As I mentioned the recv call is returning only 8 bytes even though wireshark sees 300.

Comment: I also explained the exact situation here. recv seems to only be reading up to the first 00 byte whereas wireshark is reading past it. Basically I need an explanation as to why recv cannot read past a 00 byte.

Comment: At the time the comment was made there was no code to back the claim of no `strlen`, leaving that possibility on the table. You have provided more information, but still not enough. `recv` can read past a zero byte. Since it isn't in your case, and all we've been given is a single line that by itself should work, the bug must be elsewhere.  Consider playing a few rounds of divide and conquer to narrow the scope of the problem by eliminating all code that can be removed from the program while still reproducing the problem. Read [mcve] for suggestions and inspiration.

Comment: @AubreyRussell "*recv seems to only be reading up to the first 00 byte whereas wireshark is reading past it*" - That is not how `recv` works. It doesn't look at, or care about, the actual bytes inside the datagram at all. If the sender sends X bytes, `recv()` will read and return `min(X, buffer_length)` bytes. The actual values of the bytes are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is message-oriented, not stream-oriented like TCP is.

In UDP, the *only* way that `recv()` would return 8 bytes is if either:

- you set the `len` parameter to `> 8`, and a datagram containing exactly 8 bytes is received.
- you set the `len` parameter to `== 8`, and a datagram containing more than 8 bytes is received.

Given your claim that that you are setting the `len` to 1500, then the only possibility is that the datagram received only has 8 bytes in it, not 299 bytes like you claim.

Unlike in TCP, in UDP you cannot read a datagram in pieces, a read is an all-or-nothing operation (unless you peek the data, which you are not doing).  In UDP, `recv()`/`recvfrom()` reads whole datagrams at a time, and if the provided buffer is too small to receive the data (which it is not in this case) then an `WSAEMSGSIZE` error is reported and the data is truncated, discarding the rest of the data that does not fit in the buffer.

The `00` null bytes you describe have NO EFFECT WHATEVER on `recv()`/`recvfrom()`'s ability to read a whole datagram.  A datagram carries a payload length, and `recv()`/`recvfrom()` will read up to that payload length or the specified buffer size, whichever is smaller, regardless of the actual payload content.

So, chances are, in your code, `recv()` is simply not receiving the datagram you are expecting.

For instance, in order to use `recv()` in UDP at all, you must `connect()` the UDP socket first to associate it with a specific peer IP/port, thus allowing `recv()` to ignore inbound datagrams from other peers (and for `send()` to send datagrams to a specific peer).  Maybe you are `connect`'ing your UDP socket to the wrong peer, and thus reading datagrams that are meant for something else.  Or, maybe you are `connect`'ing to the correct peer and it really is sending an 8-byte datagram that you are not expecting.

Since you did not provide *any* context info about your setup, the peer involved, the protocol involved, the Wireshark capture, nothing, there is really no way for anyone here to diagnose your situation with any certainty.  But, what I described above would account for the symptom you have described.  If you feel that is not the case, then you need to edit your question to provide more details.